# passing column names in functions as strings and evaluate with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I see gobs of posts about passing column names as strings to function but none of them consider this use case.  All the methods I see don't work. Here is one. Please compare the `what_I_want` column to the `what_I_get` column below.  I want the value of items in the column, not the column name, of course. Thanks.

```
library(dplyr)
Fun <- function(df,column) {
   df %>%
      mutate(what_I_want = cyl) %>% 
      # current best practice?  Doen't work in this case.
      mutate(what_I_get := {{column}})
}

mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% Fun("cyl")
#>               mpg cyl disp what_I_want what_I_get
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160           6        cyl
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160           6        cyl
```

Created on 2022-11-07 with reprex v2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `get`

```
Fun <- function(df,column) {
df %>%
  mutate(what_I_want = get(column) )
}

mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% Fun("cyl")
             mpg cyl disp what_I_want
Mazda RX4      21   6  160           6
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160           6
```

Comment: and that was in none of the other answers to this problem when I searched SO.  And it's a base R function. 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We may use `ensym` which can take both quoted as well as unquoted column name

```
Fun <- function(df,column) {
   df %>%
      mutate(what_I_want = !! rlang::ensym(column)) 
    
}
```

-testing

```
> mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% Fun("cyl")
              mpg cyl disp what_I_want
Mazda RX4      21   6  160           6
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160           6
> mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% Fun(cyl)
              mpg cyl disp what_I_want
Mazda RX4      21   6  160           6
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160           6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.data` pronoun you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

Fun <- function(df,column) {
  df %>%
    mutate(what_I_get = .data[[column]])
}

mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% 
  Fun("cyl")
#>               mpg cyl disp what_I_get
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160          6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160          6
```

For more on the `.data` pronoun see [Data mask programming patterns](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html#names-patterns).